# What was the name of Ashrama of sage Valmiki?

Tags: ramayana, valmiki, ashram

According to [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kusha_(Ramayana)), In the Ramayana, pregnant Sita was banished from the kingdom of Ayodhya by Rama due to gossip of the kingdom folk.

She then took refuge in the ashram of the sage Valmiki located on the banks of the Tamsa River.

The Ashrama of sage Valmiki was at the banks of Tamaas river as per this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamsa_River).

What was the name of the Ashrama of sage Valmiki? Does it have a specific name?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it had a specific name, but my best guess is Brahmāvarta. According to the “Geographical Dictionary Of Ancient And Mediaeval India”, the modern equivalent of Vālmiki Aśrama is known as Bithoor [(source)](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.106519/2015.106519.Geographical-Dictionary-Of-Ancient-And-Mediaeval-India-With-As-Appendix-On-Modern-Names-Of-Ancient-Indian-Geography#page/n113/mode/2up). Now Bithoor, according to wikipedia, equals Brahmāvarta [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bithoor), and is known as the “land of the sages”[(source)](https://www.google.nl/search?q=Brahmavarta+valmiki&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=G1Z4Wp7RJ6fH8AeiiIngCA) and “abode of gods” [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmavarta). It is known as a holy spot (*tīrtha*), according to Monier-Williams [(source)](http://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?q=brahm%C4%81varta).

Also see this page:

> Valmiki Ashram, deriving its name from the sage Valmiki, is located at a height and is accessible by a flight of stairs, which is known as the stairway to heaven. From the location of the Ashram, one can have a panoramic view of Bithoor. Brahmavart Ghat is considered the holiest of the ghats of Bithoor. 
>   [source](http://www.kvunnao.ac.in/english-visitingplaces)